# My npm package written without Typescript requires a declaration file on installation

Tags: reactjs, npm, typescript-typings

I published a super basic npm package. I'm planning to publish some of my React components but I started with a very simple package as a test. The installation worked, but when I imported a module into another project, there is a declaration warning.

The module works in the new project and it renders, but it has this error message:
"Could not find a declaration file for module 'skylight-react'. '/Users/{my-name}/{project-root}/node_modules/skylight-react/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/skylight-react` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'skylight-react';`ts(7016)"

The package I wrote (skylight-react) is written without Typescript. The `package.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "skylight-react",
  "version": "0.3.0",
  "private": false,
  "main": "dist/index",
  "module": "dist/index",
  "typings": "dist/index",
  "files": [ "dist", "README.md" ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/jawblia/components.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build-examples": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build": "rm -rf dist && NODE_ENV=production babel src/lib --out-dir dist --copy-files --ignore __tests__,spec.js,test.js,__snapshots__"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.13.14",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.14",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.12"
  }
}
```

The `.babelrc` is

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Neither the package I published nor I project I imported uses Typescript. Any help is very appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you sure it's an error and not just a warning?

Comment: @zero298 The module is rendering so I guess it's technically a warning message. But I'd still like to suppress it/figure out why it's happening.

Comment: Presumably your new project *is* using TypeScript - it doesn't matter whether or not the package also uses TS (you'll ship JS anyway) you'll need to tell the compiler what it contains *somehow*. The easiest way is to include a .d.ts in the package when you publish it, then *everyone* who consumes it gets types.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh okay, I think I see. Is it true all React npm packages exported without declarations would throw this warning, because it's assumed they can be used with TS?

Comment: Yes, because the compiler *couldn't* find any declarations, so you either need to install the package that contains them (conventionally `@types/<package>`) or provide them yourself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okay, so it sounds like the easiest thing is to figure out how to include a .d.ts in the package itself? I know basically nothing about TS.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `package.json` entries to contain the extension and be relative. `./dist/index.d.ts` has to exist, if not then write the components in TypeScript instead and use  `declaration: true` in your `tsconfig.json` or declare the typings by your self.

Also, do not publish packages without testing them locally and set up `.gitignore` as well as `.npmignore`. I suggest you read [this](https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-use-npm-link-7375b6219557) and [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-unscoped-public-packages) guide before publishing to npm.

```
{
  ...
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "module": "./dist/index.js",
  "typings": "./dist/index.d.ts"
  ...
}
```